# Is it wrong to set viewModel as table views datasource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, design-patterns, mvvm

I have seen many codes where set ViewModel as a table view data source, and many which don't.

1.Setting data source to the ViewModel some time makes sense as the data source methods mainly deal with the presentation logic.

2.On the other hand setting the ViewModel as the data source implies that you are implementing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` etc which makes it not independent of `UIKit`.

What is the best way to architecture your apps, Kindly clarify?

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be, **there is no best way to architecture an app**. There are many good ways to organize your classes according to your needs.
Here is an example of how I organize my viewModel in order to show data in the table view:

PaymentSectionItem is my ViewModel

**PaymentSectionItem.h**

```
@interface PaymentSectionItem : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger itemID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *elements;
@property (assign, nonatomic) kTransactionType transactionType;

+ (NSArray<PaymentSectionItem *> *)allSectionItemsWithData;

@end
```

**PaymentSectionItem.m**

```
@implementation PaymentSectionItem

#pragma mark - Custom Accessors

- (NSString *)localizedTitle {
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_section_title", self.name];
    return NSLocalizedString(title, @"Section title");
}

- (NSString *)localizedDescription {
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_section_description", self.name];
    return NSLocalizedString(title, @"Section description");
}

#pragma mark - Constructor

- (instancetype)initWithSectionItem:(kSectionItem)sectionItem {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupFromHomeSectionItem:sectionItem];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)setupFromHomeSectionItem:(kSectionItem)sectionItem {
    self.itemID = sectionItem;
    switch (sectionItem) {
        case kSectionItem1: {
            self.name = @"phones";
            self.elements = [Payment findPaymentsType1];
            break;
        }
        case kSectionItem2: {
            self.name = @"autopay";
            self.elements = [Payment findPaymentsType2];
            break;
        }
        case kSectionItem3: {
            self.name = @"trustfund";
            self.elements = [Payment findPaymentsType3];
            self.transactionType = kTransactionTypeTrustFund;
            break;
        }
        case kSectionItem4: {
            self.name = @"debitlink";
            self.elements = [Payment findPaymentsType4];
            self.transactionType = kTransactionTypeDebitLink;
            break;
        }
        case kSectionItem5: {
            self.name = @"pindebit";
            self.elements = [Payment findPaymentsType5];
            self.transactionType = kTransactionTypePINDebit;
            break;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Public

+ (NSArray<PaymentSectionItem *> *)allSectionItemsWithData {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
    [items addObject:[[PaymentSectionItem alloc] initWithSectionItem:kSectionItem1]];
    [items addObject:[[PaymentSectionItem alloc] initWithSectionItem:kSectionItem2]];
    [items addObject:[[PaymentSectionItem alloc] initWithSectionItem:kSectionItem3]];
    [items addObject:[[PaymentSectionItem alloc] initWithSectionItem:kSectionItem4]];
    [items addObject:[[PaymentSectionItem alloc] initWithSectionItem:kSectionItem5]];
    return items;
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.items = [PaymentSectionItem allSectionItemsWithData];
}



#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items[section].elements.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GTLAutoPaySectionItem *sectionItem = self.items[indexPath.section];
    NSString *identifier = [self identifierForSectionItem:sectionItem atIndex:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    UITableViewCell<PaymentCellProtocol> *paymentCell = (UITableViewCell<PaymentCellProtocol> *)cell;
    [paymentCell setupCellFromValue:sectionItem.elements[indexPath.row] withSectionItem:sectionItem];
    return cell;
}
```

As you see, in my case I have a table view with many sections and each section has elements. That's exactly what I do in my ViewModel. Feel free to ask if you have any other question.

Comment: I am aware of this solution, I was looking for - 1. a swift solution 2. An answer for the dilema "Where should cellForRowAtIndexPath: go? in vc or in vm and why?

Comment: I am also aware of the solution where you write the methods to get the number of rows, section for table view and a method to get cell configuration data inside View Model and call them inside VC. That makes a lot of sense but isn't it a bit of overkill? and you are really not reducing the number of lines in your VC too. And the fact that Apple put "cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method inside data source means it does not exactly belong to view layer either. Hope you Understood my dilemma, I am sure many others have it too.

Comment: @SuhasAithal: Reducing lines in secondary, the primary target should be to make readable, understandable, maintainable etc. Number of lines doesn't say the code is wrong, it eases others to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

**NO,** it is not wrong to set view model as data source, acting as data model.

Well, the book says, keep M, V & C separate for readability and maintainability. But now we have multiple design patterns to keep things simpler. Basically in a Model we only store the data, and its manipulation are done at view level, that is a good way to achieve the View.

You can not always have a tightly coupled or loosely coupled M & V. It depends on the complexity of these two.

Comment: Let me wait for other knowledgeable persons to reply before accepting any answer. thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewModel**

What you are suggesting is not wrong. In my opinion, a view model is trivial logic only, like fonts and colours. As far as I am aware no one has declared a rule for this but I would expect a view model to be simple.

Where your table view is located should be irrelevant to your model, in my opinion. Let's say the superview of your tableView was a UITableViewCell. In that case, I would connect the logic through callbacks.

So the callback would be this.

```
protocol EventTableViewCellDatasource: class {
  func showTimesTableViewDatasource() -> UITableViewDataSource
}
```

And the cell would do this

```
class EventTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  weak var datasource: EventTableViewCellDatasource?

  @IBOutlet weak private var tableView: ShowTimesTableView! {
    didSet {
      tableView.dataSource = datasource?.showTimesTableViewDatasource()
    }
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Hi, if view model is only required for font and colors, cant we achieve using Xcode run-time attributes? or something like pixate?  Why you need MVVM for that? again as I told in my comment for Luzo's answer this makes it MVVM not applicable or relevant for many ios apps.

Comment: I didn't say fonts and colours only. If you can find a way to assign a font using Xcode run-time attributes then feel free. It is not wrong to do it that way. I wouldn't consider a view model to be a subclass only. The Xcode run-time attributes also seems like a view model to me. So I don't understand your questions about MVVM.

Comment: "I wouldn't consider a view model to be a subclass only" . oh ok. Thanks for your answer.